# Concatenation not working in flutter, instead, variable breaks into two lines?

Tags: flutter, dart

So, this is a very small problem, but totally annoying!

This is my code:

```
print('COORDINATES -> ${lat}:${lng}');
```

As you can see, it should print out, example: '74.23132:47.13123' right?

But instead it goes like this..

```
    flutter: COORDINATES -> 74.23132:
47.13123
```

Is it really suppose to work like that in flutter?

Best regards!

flutter doctor -v

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.7.8+hotfix.3, on Mac OS X 10.14.5 18F203, locale en-GB)
    • Flutter version 1.7.8+hotfix.3 at /Users/usr/Developer/flutter
    • Framework revision b712a172f9 (9 days ago), 2019-07-09 13:14:38 -0700
    • Engine revision 54ad777fd2
    • Dart version 2.4.0


[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 28.0.3)
    • Android SDK at /Users/usr/Library/Android/sdk
    • Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling support)
    • Platform android-28, build-tools 28.0.3
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio 3.5 Preview.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_202-release-1483-b49-5587405)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 10.2.1)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Xcode 10.2.1, Build version 10E1001
    • CocoaPods version 1.7.0

[✓] iOS tools - develop for iOS devices
    • ios-deploy 1.9.4

[✓] Android Studio (version 3.5)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio 3.5 Preview.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin version 37.1.3
    • Dart plugin version 191.7830
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_202-release-1483-b49-5587405)

[✓] Connected device (2 available)
    • Mattias’s iPhone • aaf4a41bc5a93fcf273e2070e19ec2a6a3f37921 • ios • iOS 12.3.1
    • iPhone Xʀ        • 93F3E348-5835-492B-B756-CCD1BAD6C8E8     • ios • com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-12-2 (simulator)
```

**• No issues found!**

Comment: have you checked your variables?

Comment: What's wrong with the printed log? What did you expect?

Comment: Could you post your 'flutter doctor -v' command line output

Comment: PROBLEM: The print is not on a single line, its on two lines.

Comment: @F-1 edited my post, see the output

Comment: Make a new String variable with `$lat:$lng` as its value, and then write that variable in `print(..)`

Comment: Would I be correct in thinking this issue is only present in the Terminal but not the Debug Console?

Comment: You don't need the interpolation brackets here (ie you can write `$lat:$lng`)

Comment: Anyway, I tried all of your suggestion, without brackets, with brackets, creating a new variable etc, still something is wrong cause I can't get the data from the database which is registered under the coordinates for the point on the map.

Comment: Could you try it in your IDE and see if you get the same result, or if it actually is something wrong with the new flutter-update maybe? (v1.7.8+hotfix.3)

Comment: I was thinking it might be the version, I'm on the dev channel and it works fine, text appears on one line.

Comment: I'm curious what output will be with `print('COORDINATES -> 74.23132:47.13123');`

Comment: @F-1 Very strange, I moved to dev channel and still it's a new line for second variables..

Comment: @Eugene Already tried that, and that works fine. I think there's something causing it where as the dollarsign and semicolon is placed, that combo probably somehow breaks the line.. e.g. this combo I mean -> :$

Comment: @RusbenWladiskoz what if `print('COORDINATES -> ${lng} : ${lat}');` swapped positions lat and lng and added spaces

Comment: @Eugene When doing so, both lng and lat moved to the second line, and COORDINATES -> on first line. I'm pretty sure the problem is because it's two variables rather then one, cause even when I removed the colon, the second variable were moved to the second line.

Comment: Either your console window is too small or `lng` is a `String` that contains an embedded newline character. Otherwise provide a [minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Pretty sure that `lat` starts with a newline character. Try to print *only* `:${lat}` and see if you get the newline.

Comment: @JJJ Nope, I've tried to print both ONLY lat, and lng, they come at one line. I'm sure there's something wrong with dart/flutter

Comment: You said earlier that swapping the variables makes both of them print on a new line, so it must be caused by what the `lat` variable contains. And given that no-one here can replicate the bug, no-one has ever reported a similar bug, and this is an extremely common use case, it's most likely that it's caused by something in your own code.

Comment: Not really, I believe the swapping wasn't the solution. It were 100% because of the spacing etc, please have a look at that post again Sir. Also, I mentioned that by doing so, BOTH lat and lng were printed on a New line.

Comment: @JJJ Also, it might be because both lat and lng are parameters, probably that's what caused this bug. I'll definitely look into this later this weekend and will post a full solution, and cause of the problem!

Comment: I didn't say that swapping was a solution, I said that it proves that there's something wrong with the variable, not in the library or language itself. If `"coordinates ${lat}:${lng}"` puts only `lng` on the second line but `"coordinates ${lng}:${lat}"` puts both of them on the second line, then obviously it just prints a newline before the variable `lng` no matter where it is. If it were a bug in the language then it would be consistent and print the newline always before the second variable, not "stick" to one specific variable.

Comment: @JJJ Well, it's not that obvious in the programming world, right? You should now. Even if I'm a sort of newbie, I understand that if "coordinates ${lng}:${lat}" on same line would mean that before lng something is smacked! But what if if "coordinate{$lng}" is on the same line, not creating a new line? Then it's very unobvious right? And that's actually what happened when I tried only putting lng. Also, there could be a bug that is very very unusual, and I believe so it is.

Answer (score -5):

**SOLUTION**

After trying every logic step to accomplish this, it turns out that the flutter-team hasn't supported this yet! So don't even get into this ever, until flutter support two variables in concatenating. Very very sad to let you know!

Comment: You are wrong. See [this Gist](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/1cad0d3742c52439b2a75da4dc480840). Maybe your console window is too small..

Comment: Pretty much *any* `toString` implementation of a Flutter class uses Dart string interpolation to concatenate stringified versions of variables, and they do not exhibit this problem.  If you believe there is a bug, provide sample code that can reproduce the problem.